# disabled option added to node not working with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi I'm using vuetify and I created that directive so I can disable all child elements of the parent that has the "disableAll" atributte, It's working perfect with some elements (like normal inputs text), but when it's a type of checkbox ( like a switch ) they don't get disabled... could vuetify be the reason for that ?
I printed the "Nodes" const and inside of that the checkbox are there. So it's finding the elements and it applies the disabled property but simply doesn't work

*This is the directive*

```
 directives: {
        
    disableAll: {

      componentUpdated: (el) => {
        const tags = ['input', 'button', 'textarea', 'select'];
        tags.forEach(tagName => {
          const nodes = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
          for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i].disabled = true;
            nodes[i].tabIndex = -1;
          }
        });
      }
    },
```

*this is the html of a Switch*

```
 <div class="col">
   <div class="v-input my-0 v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-input--selection-controls v-input--switch primary--text">
      <div class="v-input__control">
         <div class="v-input__slot">
            <div class="v-input--selection-controls__input">
               <input aria-checked="true" id="input-414" role="switch" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" value="true" disabled tabindex="-1">
               <div class="v-input--selection-controls__ripple primary--text"></div>
               <div class="v-input--switch__track theme--light primary--text"></div>
               <div class="v-input--switch__thumb theme--light primary--text">
                  <!---->
               </div>
            </div>
            <label for="input-414" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: relative;">Habilitar cartas</label>
         </div>
         <div class="v-messages theme--light primary--text">
            <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and as you can see in this line

```
<input aria-checked="true" id="input-414" role="switch" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="false" value="true" disabled tabindex="-1">
```

The disabled property is being applied
it simply doesn't work

I know that vuetify has its own Disabled property that you can add to every Node, or this disabled property used in forms. But I was trying to customize this using directives because there is some elements I don't need to have disabled.

Comment: Inside `v-switch`, that checkbox is invisible (its opacity is 0). So either disabled or not, you will not see any rendered effect.

Comment: @Sphinx I guess part of the question I made you in your answer is related to this

Answer (score 1):

If only want to activate the UI effect for `v-switch`, don't change the component state, simply you can add className=`v-input--is-disabled` into its Dom of `v-switch` like below demo:

```js
Vue.directive('disable-all', {
  inserted: function (el) {
    el.querySelectorAll('div.v-input.v-input--switch').forEach(item => {
      item && item.classList.add('v-input--is-disabled')
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      switches: [true, false],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container
      class="px-0"
      fluid
      v-disable-all
    >
      <v-switch
        v-model="switches[0]"
        :label="`Switch 1: ${switches[0].toString()}`"
      ></v-switch>
      <v-switch
        v-model="switches[1]"
        :label="`Switch 1: ${switches[1].toString()}`"
      ></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I guess using this option of adding the v-input--is-disabled works (because applies the vuetify style), but I still don't understand why if I use the disable html option it doesnt work, it kind of doesn't make sense...
Another thing I realised with your code is that if I use the vuetify property disabled in a v-switch component and I delete this part "v-input--is-disabled" in the html page, the v-switch is totally deactivated ( I can't do anything even when I delete that in the class), but if I use your code and I delete "v-input--is-disabled" the v-switch works totally normal

Comment: because above directive only adds `v-input--is-disabled` into rendered dom, it will not affect `v-switch` vnode state.

Comment: so after all, it would be a bad practice to implement this in the way we are doing it adding a simple class or adding the disabled (as I posted in the question) isn't it ?

Comment: yes, uses Vuetify property always is recommended. :)